# How to upgrade bootstrap version for my Old Project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5, upgrade

I have my old project written by old bootstrap 3.3.6 classes. Now I want to use the features of bootstrap 5.2 but it's not straight forward to just change the version of the bootstrap. What's the best way to do this upgrade? Do I need to change all the code again?

I tried by to change the latest version CDN but all my project will be broke

Answer (score 0):

Go through this document: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/

After the change, your project will be broken. Just change the class names in HTML code. Your site will be fine. But it will be tough because you have to check all your code.

Comment: have you know any quick method to upgrade version because it take too much time to check all classes of bootstrap

Comment: I am afraid there is none.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Bootstrap 5 Migrate Tool script which scans all pages/templates in a folder and replaces all the Bootstrap 4 classes with Bootstrap 5 classes. It also replaces deprecated components (such as .jumbotron and .media) with utility classes, renames all the data attributes (such as data-toggle and data-target) to the new names and updates all Bootstrap v4 CDN links (jsdelivr.net, unpkg.com and stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com) to latest version of Bootstrap v5.

https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-5-migrate-tool